# Small and extra small screen testing - Should I trust resizing browser or Chrome toggle?

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm developing my first web and I am checking with the browser if layout looks as intended. Using my Chrome browser and reducing the size manually on the HTML files, all the bootstrap columns align as intended for medium and small screens. However, when I use the Chrome device toggle (`Ctrl+Shift+I`), the medium and small screens do not look as intended.

Which source is more reliable to know how the web will look on a phone? The toggle or manually downsizing the window?

[image: Chrome device toggle]

Comment: have you added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to you head tag as we can not see from your screen shot

Comment: @BradHolmes Yes, it was added to the html file. So that makes the "manual resizing of the Chrome browser" as a reliable indicator on how the web would look on a narrow/phone screen? Sorry if the question is too basic, really very first web I am developing :/